# Media queries not working in iframes on Iphone

Tags: iphone, iframe, media-queries

I'm doing responsive website. I tried it on every browser and everything is ok, however than I displaying that page on iphone  i notice a bug, media queries in css on iframe not working in the page. Any ideas how to make it work?

Here is the page: http://saulesmiestas.lt/lt/aukstu_planai/1

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Well, I've found kind of solution, I add media query specificly for iphone and it worked.